# User with edit privileges made files I own not viewable by me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I shared a folder containing files and subfolders with files with multiple users and gave them edit permissions. One users account has modified the viewing ability(?) of every file and subfolder they had access to. From my account when I open the top level folder I see it empty but I know these files are still there because I own the majority of them and my drive storage amount hasn't changed.

The user claims they have no idea how it happened so maybe that it was an app they unknowingly gave drive access to?

Is there any way I can fix this from the Google Drive web interface? I found Google Apps Scripts has access to the Drive API, should I find a script that can mass change the permissions?

Comment: Are you the Admin?

Comment: @Cooper no I am not the admin of the domain of this folder and do not have access to domain controls.

Comment: Well, since you can't see the files any longer I'm guessing that Drive API won't help you.  But you could go to API explorer and get a list of files in that directory.  If you get the list  (which I doubt) then you might be able to affect the desired change.  I would recommend that you get your admin involved.  I believe that they will be able to make the desired changes.  In the future you might want to be a little more careful about sharing your files.  Perhaps give readonly access.

Comment: @Cooper I will try that but they may not respond. Alternatively, Would the Drive API be useful if I wrote a script for the user who changed all permissions to run? They seem willing to help fix the issue but doing on their own is above their head.

Comment: I'm still a neophyte when it comes to Drive API so I wouldn't even try something on anyone elses drive until I've had more practice on mine.  But in any event I'd be upset if I were the admin and you didn't contact me before doing anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Only the owner can delete the file.

The files were removed from the folder but were not deleted.
Therefore, they take up disk space.

To view files outside the folder, follow these steps:

https://drive.google.com/drive/search?q=is:unorganized%20owner:me

Excuse my bad English
Venca